# Python3 and networkx=2.2: set_node_attributes and getting unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have been using networkx, but I am trying to add a new attribute do the graph using

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'Pi', PiDict)
```

I am getting:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/classes/function.py", line 656, in set_node_attributes
    G.nodes[n][name] = values

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

G is:

```
nx.info(G)
Out[5]: 'Name: \nType: DiGraph\nNumber of nodes: 20\nNumber of edges: 72\nAverage in degree:   3.6000\nAverage out degree:   3.6000'
```

PiDict is a dictionary:

```
{0: 0.12500000001440292,
 1: 0.03125000000360126,
 2: 0.03125000000360079,
 3: 0.03125000000360083,
 4: 0.03125000000360079,
 5: 0.12499999999611916,
 6: 0.031249999999029825,
 7: 0.031249999999029828,
 8: 0.031249999999029828,
 9: 0.03124999999902983,
 10: 0.12499999999082015,
 11: 0.03124999999770508,
 12: 0.03124999999770508,
 13: 0.03124999999770508,
 14: 0.031249999997705075,
 15: 0.12499999999865749,
 16: 0.03124999999966442,
 17: 0.03124999999966442,
 18: 0.031249999999664425,
 19: 0.03124999999966442}
```

I solved this by

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'Pi', 1)
for i,value in enumerate(PiList):
    G.nodes[i]['Pi'] = PiDict[i]
```

What is the problem with my previous code? Is there a correct way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different argument order.

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, PiDict, 'Pi')
```

What your solution has done is to give each node an attribute whose name is `1` and whose value is `'Pi'`.  Then you assign to each node another attribute `'Pi'` whose value is the value you want.  To check that, do `G.nodes(data=True)` after you've assigned the attributes.